# Understanding possession

Tags: reference-request, possession

In [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/4488/111) to the question [How does expressing possession vary across language families?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/4487/111), there is a classification on some types of Possession across languages. I have tried to look for an overview of Possession in general and also on the different types of it, but I didn't find much so I'd like to ask some questions:

1. Are those classifications only according to Stassen, from his book Predicative Possession or from a more general perspective?
2. Why does the answer defines them "values of the parameter" and not "types", I'm a bit confused by this wording.
3. Finally, where could I find an exhaustive but general overview of possession?

Comment: I think it would be better to ask your first to clarifying questions directly to the authors in the other question. Or, please quote the relevant parts here for us.

Answer (score 1):

1. I am not aware of disputes regarding the classification of predicative possession, so I wouldn't say it's "just" Stassen. Note, though, that his book (like the name says) is primarily concerned with predicative possession and not as much with other forms of possession. For example, "that car is mine" is a predicative expression that expresses possession, but "you crashed my car" is not predicative, while still containing a possessive. Furthermore there are other features of [possession](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_%28linguistics%29) that are independent of whether possession is predicative, e.g. [obligatory possession](http://wals.info/chapter/58) or [possessive classes](http://wals.info/chapter/59).
2. The answer uses "value of parameter" and "type" exchangably (you can see "type" mentioned below the list). "value of parameter" follows the usage of WALS (the answer linked the map, [here's the chapter text](http://wals.info/chapter/117)) which follows general linguistic usage ([presumably originating here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_and_parameters)) where a parameter is a specific construction which can take different forms (= values) in different languages.
3. I don't have any particular reference ready. I often see *"Possession: Cognitive sources, forces, and grammaticalization." by Heine, Bernd (1997), ISBN 978-0-521-02413-6* referenced, but I haven't read it, so I cannot tell you whether it would help you. Maybe go to a nearby university with a linguistics department and ask in the library for what they do have on possession?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have already that book, I was looking for more material but if you suggested that, then it makes it a good source. :D